# Magento cant make an order

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

I have an installation of Magento 1.9.2. I am using a custom theme, and anytime I try and place an order it kicks off the ajax on the page and then stops with no error messages, but does leave a log:

> ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or
>   rolled back  in /html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039

I have spent 2 days trying to get to the bottom of this with no joy. It doesnt matter what payment method I use its always the same.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You have the problem, that the transaction somewhere started is neither commited nor rolledback, this means, somewhere an error is thrown which stops the code to process the `rollback()` or `commit()` a few lines later.

The code you provide does not help to find the problem.

Ideas to find it:

- Activate the `query_log` from mysql, reload the page and check what the
  last query is, which is fired, then debug from there what happens
  check the exception.log and activate the debug mode if it is not yet
  activated and check for errors
- Where is the `print_r` located which produces the output? maybe this
  helps? Hook with your debugger of choice (I'm sure you have one, if
  not CHANGE IT!) into `Mage::run` and all the `catch` statements, maybe
  your exception is catched there.
- Whatever happens, you have to find this place and check what get's
  wrong. Such errors are hard to debug.